# Node js tasks, collecting data, serving web and sending data from beaglebone

Tags: javascript, node.js, real-time, sensors, beagleboneblack

I am starting a project and searching for the technology to use, I would like to use node js and javascript for the whole project but my app needs to collect data from sensors at specific time intervals, let's say 10ms, send collected data to a web service and serve a web page for configuration.
My question is if i can, with node js, be confident that the time interval is going to be fulfilled and how can i acomplished this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is more of an generic question with multiple different answers. Please narrow down your question by doing some research in the area first.

Comment: You've tagged this with real-time -- do you *need* the samples to be taken at the correct times, or is okay for them to be off (delayed) on occasion? If you do in fact need real-time (as in reliability in meeting the data collection deadlines), then you will not be able to do so in Javascript.

Comment: You might alos want to consider node-RED (a graphical node.js development environment) http://nodered.org for this task. I have been able to read analogue inputs at around 100Hz on a Beaglebone using node-RED, though I would say that is pushing it a bit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usage of setInterval is not a good idea, because it does not wait for end of handler execution and can start another one immediately after previous. It means that you will not have guarantee of interval, setInterval just put your handler into event loop using specified interval, but your handler may work more time that interval for some reason and event loop queue just could be overflowed.

I think it is better to use schedulers with setTimeout like [this one](https://www.npmjs.org/package/pragma-scheduler)

Answer (score 0):

Node will do just fine for this. As node is a JavaScript runtime, you have access to all of the JavaScript language. Doing something at a 10ms interval is trivial:

```
setInterval(function () {
  // do your check for updates
}, 10);
```